# How do I use only one element of an ArrayList? Java

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, element

If I have an initialized array in Java and I want to do a method to one element in that array I would do

array[n].method();

but how do I do the same thing with an arraylist?

arraylist[n].method() gives me an error.

Comment: Which language? What error?

Comment: java sorry. and it says array required, but java.util.ArrayList found

Comment: @moveslikeswagger See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html as well as http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm.

Answer (score 2):

With Java use get method with ArrayList:

```
arraylist.get(n).method();
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working... I don't know a lot about java but doesn't .get() just return the element at that spot? I can't actually edit the element, for the same reason I can't change a letter in a string by saying string.charAt(3)='a';  . Or maybe I'm completely wrong and I just made a mistake in my code somewhere.

Comment: @moveslikeswagger You asked what the equivalent of `array[n].method()` was for an `ArrayList`. This answer is precisely that equivalent. Also it is not the same as your example of trying to use assignment to modify a character with `string.charAt(3) = 'a'` - *that* would be equivalent to trying to do `arraylist.get(n) = ...`, which you cannot do, but that's not related to what you're asking about here. Calling a method on an object in an `ArrayList` is perfectly fine. If "it doesn't seem to be working" you'll have to add more detail, perhaps in a new question.